# Javascript only allow certain format

Tags: javascript

the title states my question..here's the supposed format

```
<input type="text" value="2010-12414" onkeyup="isformat(this)">
```

and the script i have is this

```
function isformat(ele)
                {
                   var r=/\D-\D$/i;
                   if(r.test(ele.value))
                    {
                         alert("This Field allows Only Numerics.");
                         ele.value="";
                        ele.focus();
                     }
                }
```

i'm not sure if it is the correct argument. Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Using regular expressions for this is a good call but why are you alerting and emptying the field? perhaps it'd be better doing so with some colors.. and an inline warning..

Comment: so the var r is correct for my required input?

Comment: What is the pattern? always dddd-ddddd ?

Comment: yes. that's the format i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `dddd-ddddd` use:

```
var re = /^\d{4}-\d{5}$/;
```

(*Start-of-string > digit > repeated-4-times > hyphen > digit > repeated-5-times > end-of-string*)

Comment: great. thanks for this. marking this one in few minutes